# How to calculate time difference in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have Rails application which using MYSQL as database. For some condition, I have to delete all the records from table which was stored exactly 2 hours before the current time.

My query is :

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (NOW() - created_at) > 7200;
```

Here create_at is datetime column type. Storing the value in the format "2012-12-04 06:39:44"

My problem is, the above query fetch the records even though the record created time is just 40 to 50 minutes and got deleted.  The only problem is the record got delete after it reach 40 to 50 minx from it create time.

Can any one please correct my query. I want the MySQL solution. Please help me

Comment: You are mixing different data types in the same expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need this if you want to delete records created exactly 2 hours ago:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE created_at = NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

or this, that will delete all records created more than 2 hours ago:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

Comment: Thanks Fthiella, Let me try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Try this ::

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TIMEDIFF(NOW(),created_at) < '02:00:00';
```

Comment: Will give try and let you know guys

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE created_at<DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

This query will delete everything created MORE THAN 2 hours ago. Putting an equal sign would mean EXACTLY 2 hours ago (in second). Of course you can format date to consider only minutes, but that would slow down the query.
If created_at is indexed (and I think it should be) don't perform any functions on it so it can use index to perform delete faster.

Comment: In my case I have interval applied to NOW(). That leaves created_at column untouched so it can use index to perform delete faster.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to delete all records created within a time lapse. So, you shouldn't apply a "greater than" operator to the subtract operation. Instead you should try to specify an appropriated time frame.

You could also take a look to the timediff function  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Sorry I'm not able to post the right statement for you, since I don't have a mysql server at hand.